# Why won't this variable gain the value of the other variable?

Tags: python

Sorry for the confusing title, I couldn't really think of how to phrase this.
Essentially, I have the code below.

For some reason, the 'back' variable won't become the random variable. There's no error message, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Bonus points: how do I set this in a loop so that it will automatically set the previous values as the 'starter' values?

```
#import random
import random
randomCard = ("X", "O")
front = ""
back = ""
rand = random.choice(randomCard)

#ask what's on front
starterFront = input("What's on front? (Starter)")
starterBack = input("What was on back?")
print("")

#start
front = input("What's on front?")
if front == "X" and starterFront == "X" and starterBack == "X":
  back = "O"
  print(back)
if front == "X" and starterFront == "X" and starterBack == "O":
  back = (random.choice(randomCard))
  print(back)
if front == "O" and starterFront == "O" and starterBack == "X":
  back = (random.choice(randomCard))
  print(back)
if front == "X" and starterFront == "O" and starterBack == "X":
  back = (random.choice(randomCard))
  print(back)
if front == "O" and starterFront == "X" and starterBack == "O":
  back = (random.choice(randomCard))
  print(back)
```

Comment: "sorry, I'm dumb and can't figure out how to input code for the life of me" - copy-paste your code from a source file into the question box, then select everything you pasted (including the parts that look okay in the preview) and hit Ctrl-K or the button with the braces.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help regarding how to format code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: In particular, I don't know what you mean for the `back` variable to become the random variable.  `back` takes on a random value from `X` `O`, just as you've coded it.  What output do you get, and what do you expect?  Also, please make this independently reproducible (don't make us enter test values), and cut the problem down to minimal size: you assign to `back` in five places; one or two should be enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your back variable is recalling the random choice `back = (random.choice(randomCard))` so it will not be the same as the random variable. to get it to be the same just use `back = rand` which will assign back the value of rand.

To get it into a loop use a `while 'input':` loop.
The previous values should also remain the same so you should not need to do anything to them.

```
#import random
import random
randomCard = ("X", "O")
front = ""
back = ""
rand = random.choice(randomCard)

#ask what's on front
starterFront = input("What's on front? (Starter)")
starterBack = input("What was on back?")
print("")

#start
front = input("What's on front?")
while front:
    if front == "X" and starterFront == "X" and starterBack == "X":
      back = "O"
      print(back)
    if front == "X" and starterFront == "X" and starterBack == "O":
      back = rand
      print(back)
    if front == "O" and starterFront == "O" and starterBack == "X":
      back = rand
      print(back)
    if front == "X" and starterFront == "O" and starterBack == "X":
     back = rand
     print(back)
    if front == "O" and starterFront == "X" and starterBack == "O":
      back = rand
      print(back)

    front = input("What's on front?")
```

Comment: Occasionally, it prints both X and O. Why is that?